# Apple's PDFKit (or anything else), extract positions of images

Tags: image, pdf, position, pdfkit

I need to extract the positions of all images from a pdf-file on the Mac. For now I am considering PDFKit, but that if there is a better way of doing that, i'm open to suggestions.

So the question is, how can i parse a PDF file on the Mac, receiving (images, not necessarily), their positions within a page and page numbers using PDFKit or, probably, another library or even a program (I don't have to build it into my program, i just need it done).

**UPD** Seems like it is possible to do that using Adobe's Acrobat SDK.

Thanks in advance, 
Timofey.